# Can I add a 'show all pages' link to wp link pages?

Tags: wp-link-pages

I use [wp_link_pages](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_link_pages) to paginate individual pages and posts.

Is  there a way I can add to it an extra link which'll show all pages together, on a single page rather than split?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a suggestion using the `wp_link_pages` and `content_pagination` filters:

The aim is to add a "*Show All Content*" link below the content pagination links:

[image]

and when we click it, the link should display "*Show Content Pagination*" and vice versa.

**Demo plugin**

We can do that with the following demo, where we introduce the `wpse_show_all_content` GET variable:

```
add_filter( 'wp_link_pages', function( $output, $args )
{
    // Validate user input
    $show_all_content = (bool) filter_input( 
        INPUT_GET, 
        'wpse_show_all_content', 
        FILTER_VALIDATE_BOOLEAN 
    ); 

    // Generate link
    $link = add_query_arg( 
        'wpse_show_all_content', 
        ! $show_all_content, 
        get_permalink() 
    );

    // Generate link title
    $title = $show_all_content 
        ? 'Show Content Pagination' 
        : 'Show All Content';

    // Append    
    $output .= sprintf( 
        '<a href="%s">%s</a>', 
        esc_url( $link ),
        esc_html__( $title, 'mydomain' )
    );

    return $output;

}, 10, 2 );
```

To disable the content pagination when `wpse_show_all_content` is true, we can use (PHP 5.4+):

```
add_filter( 'content_pagination', function( $pages )
{
    // Validate user input
    $show_all_content = (bool) filter_input( 
        INPUT_GET, 
        'wpse_show_all_content', 
        FILTER_VALIDATE_BOOLEAN 
    ); 

    // Disable content pagination
    if( $show_all_content )
        $pages = [ join( '', $pages ) ];

    return $pages;

} );
```

Hope you can adjust this further to your needs!

**Update**

As per discussion, here's a way to target only a specific `wp_link_pages()` instance:

```
add_filter( 'wp_link_pages', function( $output, $args )
{
    // Nothing to do if 'wpse_show_all_link' is missing or not a true boolean string
    if( 
            ! isset( $args['wpse_show_all_link'] ) 
        ||  ! wp_validate_boolean( $args['wpse_show_all_link'] )
    )
        return output;

    // Validate user input
    $show_all_content = (bool) filter_input( 
        INPUT_GET, 
        'wpse_show_all_content', 
        FILTER_VALIDATE_BOOLEAN 
    ); 

    // Generate link
    $link = add_query_arg( 
        'wpse_show_all_content', 
        ! $show_all_content, 
        get_permalink() 
    );

    // Generate link title
    $title = $show_all_content 
        ? 'Show Content Pagination' 
        : 'Show All Content';

    // Append    
    $output .= sprintf( 
        '<a href="%s">%s</a>', 
        esc_url( $link ),
        esc_html__( $title, 'mydomain' )
    );

    return $output;
}, 10, 2 );
```

where we introduce a custom `wpse_show_all_link` attribute that can take values like

```
1, 0, '1', '0', 'yes', 'no', true, false, 'true', 'false'.
```

**Usage**:

```
wp_link_pages( ['wpse_show_all_link' => true, ...] );
```

Comment: Thanks. That does it - although it's currently showing the link twice, and I don't know enough to fix that.

Comment: Great. I tested this briefly on a vanilla install with the *Twenty Sixteen* theme so I suspect there's something affecting it in your theme or plugins. but it's difficult to say what that could be exactly  Start small and try e.g. a plain link with the wp_link_pages filter and add from there. @gulliver

Comment: Sorry, my brain must have been freewheelin'. It shows twice because I'm using wp_link_pages twice - once to show a prev/next page and then again to show the page numbers. I'll find a way to change things. Your code works well. Thanks, again. ;-) (UPDATE... https://gist.github.com/drivenfaroff/7570106 has a function which combines numbers and prev/next.)

Comment: You're welcome - good to hear you sorted it out @gulliver

Comment: Updated the answer with an example how to target a specific `wp_link_pages()` instance (untested though) @gulliver

Comment: @birgire...Thanks for the added update. I'm getting an error, so will outline my limited understanding of things... The first solution will apply to all instances of wp_link pages, whereas the update (with ['wpse_show_all_link']) will only affect instances of wp_link_pages which have args of ['wpse_show_all_link' => true]? That's what I think should happen. But using the update works fine with an instance of wp_link_pages which has args of ['wpse_show_all_link' => true] but affects other instances of wp_link pages too - which now display 'output' rather than the links.